# log script output to file and terminal at the same time

Tags: bash, tcp

I have a simple `tcpnotification` receiver script that logs notifications. At first I just printed the notifications in terminal but then changed script so that notifications are logged in a file.

But I would like the script to both print the logs in terminal and logged them to a file.

```
while true;
 do
    nc -l -p $portL >> ~/tcplog.log
    #ipv6 version
    #nc -6 -l -p $portL

 done
```

Can this be done in one command? I tried to add `printf` to `nc -l -p $portL >> ~/tcplog.log` but this just resulted in access denied. Also tried `&&` but this resulted in notifications logged once in terminal then next time in logfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `tee`

```
nc -l -p $portL |tee -a ~/tcplog.log
```

See also `man tee` for more details

Comment: Your right, i forgot about the tee command.

Thanks!