# Triggering an event based on output of a second command

Tags: bash

I'm scripting a deploy to cloud foundry using the CF CLI, and would like to capture the logs related to the new application being started up for analysis. This requires two different commands typically, `cf push [appname] -f [manifest.yml]` and `cf logs [appname] > [appname].log`. The problem is that until mid-way though the push command, the application will not exist yet, and `cf logs` requires an existing application in order to run successfully.

I think my script would have read the output stream from `cf push` to look for the line stating that the service has been created, then fire off a `cf logs` command in a second thread to capture those logs. I'm looking for a mechanism by which I could inspect the output of `cf push` and trigger that second process.

Two questions

- Is this even possible?
- What would this kind of thing even be called so I can find some documentation on a sound approach?

Comment: do you mean something like: `cf push ...etc.. | grep "service has been created" && cf logs ... etc ..` ?

Comment: I actually figured out a way to handle it by issuing the `--no-start` argument to `cf push`, which prevents the application from starting after it's deployed, this gives me a chance to fire off the `cf logs` process in the background before calling `cf start` to capture the whole startup process, but I would be interested in the answer to the original question.

Comment: does the 'cf push...' command return immediately (before the app starts/exists), or does it exit only after the app has started?

Comment: Only after the app has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `cf push` sequence completes only after it has started the service (or died trying, I suppose), you can chain together a pipeline that says (in English): "start the cf push and look for a 'success' message; if see it, run cf logs".

In shell syntax, that would be (with your example commands):

```
cf push [appname] -f [manifest.yml] | grep -q "service has been created" && \
 cf logs [appname] > [appname].log
```

This uses the shell's pipeline to connect `cf push`'s output with the `grep` command. The grep command (-q for quietly) searches for the success message (replace the string I used with what `cf push` actually produces). If grep finds the message, it will exit with a successful return code; that will allow the `&&` operator to run the `cf logs` command. If grep is not successful, the `&&` operator will *not* run the `cf logs` command. I used a `\` backslash after the `&&` just to wrap the code nicely; the commands could all be on one line.

For more reading, see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators/159514#159514)

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without suppressing the output of `cf push` on stdout?

Comment: Someone asked for the same thing earlier today! See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277580/117549 and/or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277467/log-script-output-to-file-and-terminal-at-the-same-time/277469#277469 for examples of using `tee` to do that.