# Save number of lines output to a variable in a shell script without consuming the output

Tags: shell-script, stdout, wc

I have a shell script where I have a if statement based off of the number output lines output from another call. (In my case do something there is more that 1 line of output).

```
LINES=$(function_call | wc -l)
if [ "$LINES" -gt 1 ]
  then
    do_stuff
fi
```

What I would like however is not to consume the output (ie still have it appear in stdout), but still have the script do the same thing.

Comment: What is your question here ? You already saved the output from your `function_call` to a variable. What else do you mean by "_not consuming the output_" ? What is the expected output and what do you want to do with it ? Your question is really vague.

Comment: Is this a zen question? How do you count lines of output without reading it? My only constructive thought here is to use tee to (additionally) save the output to a file, or to saved the output to a variable. Either way, the output will be "consumed", though.

Comment: I would like to be able to get the line count (so I can make decisions based off of it) and have the output appear in stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tee` (here assuming a system with support for `/dev/fd/<n>`):

```
{ 
  lines=$(function_call 3>&- | tee -a /dev/fd/3 | wc -l)
} 3>&1
if [ "$lines" -gt 1 ];  then
  do_stuff
fi
```

On Linux that has an odd implementation of `/dev/fd/<n>`, if stdout is redirected to a file, the output will be inserted *at the end* of that file even if the current position of stdout in the script in that file is not at the end (in general, that would be OK though as it's rare for stdout to be going *inside* a file).

Alternatively, you could do

```
{ 
  lines=$(function_call 3>&- | sed -ne 'w /dev/fd/3' -e '$=')
} 3>&1
```

Or:

```
{ 
  lines=$(function_call 3>&- | awk '{print > "/dev/fd/3"}; END {print NR}')
} 3>&1
```

(beware that depending on the `sed` or `awk` implementation, it may give one more than `wc -l` if `function_call` outputs extra data after the last newline character).